# Where can I find more information on spring-security annotations

Tags: java, annotations, spring-security

I am currently working on securing a web application using spring-security 3.0. I have gotten most of my issues figured out but I am trying to gain a better understanding of exactly what I am doing (copy and paste FTL).

I watched [this video](http://www.viddler.com/explore/oredev/videos/22/) in which he stated that the @Secured should not be used anymore except for certain situations. He also shows a list of annotations and methods that can be used (around 44:50) but doesnt explain them. He simply shows them being used. So I took a look through the documentation and found [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-method-security). So I add the required code to my xml file, and I try `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")` and it doesn't work. I then realize that hasAuthority is not a method (thank you documentation for confusing me). I change it to `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` and VOILA, it works.

Now, I'm wondering (other then why is the documentation wrong) where can I find more information on the pre-post-annotation types and methods that were so nicely listed in the presentation? I tried the Google but maybe I'm searching for the wrong terms. Also, JSR250 annotations were mentioned as being the proper ones to use but I have found no information on this either. Is my google broken or am I simply looking in the wrong places?

Comment: This appeared after your post: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1583

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression-based access control is better explained in documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)

Answer (score 2):

As Willie states in his comment hasAuthority has actually been [added](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1583) as a valid syntax for all those wanting to use it.
Quoting Luke Taylor from the ticket:

> I've added support for hasAuthority() and hasAnyAuthority() expressions to SecurityExpressionRoot.

Adding it as an answer as it wasn't clear to me from the current answers and thought it might help others.

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure you have the pre and post annotations enable in your security context

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

hasAuthority will work if you put 
`<security:http use-expressions="true" …`
in your application context.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a DZone Refcard explaining how to use EL in Spring Security:

http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/expression-based-authorization?oid=hom25493